# Word auto-resized columns issue – numbers are disappeared

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In Word 2013, and previous versions also, we can set table columns 's width to be auto-resized to cells 's content.

[image]

One issue of this feature occurs when we using numbering list for one column e.g. the 1st column.

The column is overlapped as below snapshot.

[image]

I tried to set the number indentation but that only helps me with the left margin i.e. the right margin is still overlapped.

[image]

Do you have the same issue? What is the workaround for me?

p.s.

My sample Word file to reproduce this issue can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfvodws4f4cqqh8/Auto-resize%20column%20issue%20in%20Word.docx?dl=1).

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue for me as well, since you ask for workarounds and not really a solution, (which doesn't seem to exist) here are my suggestions

1. Make a column heading that would be larger than the largest text say Sl. No. (which is my standard heading in most cases and probably longer in Viatnamese)
2. Autofit to Window (You postpone the issue from a single digit to two digits in this case)
3. Make the entire content first and manually set a width (I know this is really not a great suggestion)
4. Format the table with default cell margins (I actually did it only for this one column which is sufficient as shown in the snapshot)

[image]

Comment: The right cell margin is good enough for me. I'll set it for the first column and it should work.

Comment: Please extract the cell margins solution into a separated answer to get accepted - a better suggestion to set the cells option for selected column only, not-need for the default table cell.

Comment: @NamGVU I agree with you that one column is sufficient and I have modified the response, I think the SE guidelines would not allow me to post the same answer twice, may be the other suggestions may help someone else? :)

Comment: Then I can hardly accept your answer. Other workarounds are great mind indeed though a short and clean and work solution is what we need.